# Automatically set higher precision to float in C

Tags: c, numerical-methods, floating-point-precision

I would like to set automatically an higher precision to my delta_prime compared to my typedef t_float in order to avoid cancellation problems so that the user can change t_float if he wants to.
Maybe I can try to get the float precision but I do not know how I can do that properly.

In my typedefs.h :

```
typedef double t_float;
```

In some code.c :

```
t_float solve_quadratic(const t_float a, const t_float b_prime, const t_float c)
{
    long double delta_prime = b_prime * b_prime - a * c;

    if (delta_prime < 0.0)
        return INF;

    return (b_prime + sqrt(delta_prime)) / a;
}
```

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187242/quadratic-equation-error.

Comment: This does not answer my question. And in my case I want to avoid the b^2 = ac cancellation...

Comment: Have you considered if something like [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/) is a viable alternative?

Comment: `long double delta_prime` may help in `sqrt(delta_prime)`if you use `sqrtl` but it doesn't improve cancellation matters unless you cast each operand on the left hand side as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answers I will take a look at MPFR. 
Thanks for sqrtl, I was thinking C++. I think it does help according to http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~haber/math315/chap2.pdf end of p18. Did i miss something ?

Comment: If you are thinking C++, please label your question with "C++".

Comment: Actually I am writing C code but when using the sqrt i wrote it like in C++ since in C++ we do not differentiate sqrtl sqrtf, etc...

Comment: A note: `long double delta_prime = b_prime * b_prime - a * c;` does not calculate the value on the right hand side any more precisely than `t_float delta_prime = b_prime * b_prime - a * c;`. To get more precision, you must convert the operands on the right-hand side, as with `long double_prime = (long double) b_prime * b_prime - (long double) a * c;`.

Comment: Another note: Cancelation in the subtraction in `b_prime * b_prime - a*c` does not affect the accuracy of the results. In fact, if there is cancelation in the high bits, the result of the subtraction is exactly the mathematical difference of the operands, with no error, because the mathematical result fits in the floating-point format. (Such cancelation means the numbers were close together, so their bits were aligned. If the numbers had very different magnitudes, their significant bits might be in different ranges.) The critical errors occur during the multiplications, not the subtraction.

Comment: Thank you Eric for these precious explanations. If I understood correctly, in my case, there is no need to use higher precisions then I do not get the point told at [page 38 subsection 2.3.7](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~haber/math315/chap2.pdf)

Comment: There is potential cancellation in `b_prime+sqrt(delta_prime)` when `b` is negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use templates to build a "type map".  Boost's MPL has a "map" for just this, or you can do it yourself:

```
template <typename Numeric>
struct precision_enlarger;

template <>
struct precision_enlarger<float> { typedef double type; };

template <>
struct precision_enlarger<double> { typedef long double type; };

template <>
struct precision_enlarger<long double> { typedef long double type; };
```

Then in your code:

```
typename precision_enlarger<t_float>::type delta_prime = // ...
```

Comment: Thank you I will keep that for C++ code however I am writing in C.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid large loss of precision and one cannot use higher precision, one can re-arrange the calculation.

```
const t_float a, const t_float b_prime, const t_float c

// The concern here is when `a*c` is positive, no cancellation when negative.
//long double delta_prime = b_prime * b_prime - a * c;

t_float ac = a*c;
t_float Discriminant;
t_float Discriminant_sr;
if (ac <= 0.0) {
  Discriminant = b_prime * b_prime - ac;
  // or Discriminant_sq = hypot(b_prime, sqrt(-ac));
}
else {
  ac = sqrt(ac);
  // When result approaches 0.0, half the precision loss v. b_prime * b_prime - a*c
  Discriminant = (b_prime - ac) * (b_prime + ac);
  // Note: Discriminant can only be negative via this path
}

// Assume + and - root are equally valid, so use the one that does not cause cancellation.
// b_prime + sqrt(Discriminant)) / a;
Discriminant_sr = sqrt(Discriminant);
t_float Root1;
if (b_prime >= 0.0) {
  Root1 = (b_prime + Discriminant_sr) / a;
else
  Root1 = (b_prime - Discriminant_sr) / a;
return Root1;

// If the other root is needed, it likely may be calculated from _something_ like 
Root2 = c/Root1.
```